# one-one analytic function don't have vanishing derivative

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm not sure,is it possible a one-one analytic function on a simply connected region has a vanishing first order derivative at some point.I find a counter example in the real case,$y=x^3$,but I did't find a counter example in the complex case.

Comment: There is none. If the first $n$ derivatives of a holomorphic function are zero, it locally looks like $z^{n+1}$, which is not one-to-one.

Comment: ...which is $(n+1)$-to-$1$ away from $z=0$.

Comment: ...and the holomorphic function itself is $(n+1)$-to-$1$ near the point $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a further hint in addition to the comments, consider the set $z^n = \operatorname{Re} z^n$.
It looks locally like $n$ lines intersecting each other. This can be made into a proof that conformal maps $D \rightarrow D$ must have non-vanishing derivative. As you know that is not sufficient though, consider the exponential function on $D = \mathbb{C}$.

I am sure that weird things can happen at the boundary, but domain implies open by definition, or not?

Comment: The domain is open by definition.But I'm not sure about your path.It seems like an example to me.But I see your point,in John B. Conway's book "Functions of One Complex Variable",Theorem 7.4 seems to suffice to finish the proof.

Comment: No, it is the essential idea of a proof.